# How to get .vimrc ignore backtick

Tags: vim

I'm using proprietary language that has syntax similar to javascript. In my .vimrc I have set BufReadPost for the file set syntx=javascript which works for most of the part except for backtick. 
Unlike in .js, backtick is used to iterate over matrix without closing backtick. Since .vimrc is treating it like a js syntax it expects closing ` or else everything afterwards is string. How do I tell vim to ignore backtick.

Answer (score 0):

In general, modifying an existing syntax script is difficult, as there are many complexities and interactions of parsing groups. However, small adaptations are possible.

If you're using the default JavaScript syntax that ships with Vim, it uses [this definition](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/5be4ceecea5520265066eac972460ebb1cdf05e7/runtime/syntax/javascript.vim#L38) for the backticks:

```
syn region  javaScriptStringT          start=+`+  skip=+\\\\\|\\`+  end=+`+ contains=javaScriptSpecial,javaScriptEmbed,@htmlPreproc
```

To get rid of it, you can [`:help :syn-clear`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-clear) it:

```
:syntax clear javaScriptStringT
```

To apply this automatically, the command has to run *after* the syntax script has been sourced. Use the [after-directory](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#after-directory), e.g. as `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim`.

#### Alternative syntaxes

Especially in the JavaScript area, there are several competing syntax scripts. For example, I use [this one](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax); fortunately, it has a [similar syntax line](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax/blob/9e7ccf6dbe2ceae5951dc5d39457810a5662c327/syntax/javascript.vim#L188) that can be cleared in just the same way.